# How to set proxy settings not in project's gradle.properties?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, http-proxy

I need to set some proxy settings for my Android Studio (v1.5.1) project (on Ubuntu). Every time I need it (e.g. when downloading an external library), Android Studio proposes to write them to `gradle.properties`, with no other option.

Since this file is version-controlled on a git repository, I need to set them somewhere else.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `/home/user/.gradle/gradle.properties` file.

This file is not under version control and it is used by all projects in your machine.
This file is used by gradle without any setting, and you can use it to store some reserved data for example.

The configuration is applied in following order (if an option is configured in multiple locations the last one wins):

- from `gradle.properties` in **project build dir**.
- from `gradle.properties` in **gradle user home**.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add it to `gradle.properties`. You can just mark the file to be ignored by git so that you do not accidentally check in the proxy details.

OR

just momentarily switch to a public network when the proxy is blocking some network resources.

Comment: What if I have other options in gradle.properties that are required to compile my project and I have no access to public network?

Comment: If you dont have a ticket you cant ride the train.